# c# How to use an instanciated object's property(which is a list) in a function?

Tags: c#

I have two classes.
A Player Class that has the properties Name, Balance and Cards:

```
class Player
{
    public string Name;
    public decimal Balance;
    public List<Card> Cards; // My question is related to this property
}
```

And a Card class:

```
class Card
{
    public string Name;
    public int Attack;
    public int Defense;
    public decimal Cost;
}
```

I instantiated an object for the player:

```
var player = new Player("Ahmad", 100);
```

and also a card:

```
var card = new Card("Mino", 3, 3, 200);
```

then added the card to the player's Cards:

```
player.Cards[0] = card;
```

I can simply display it on the main method where it was instantiated but the **Problem is**: How can I access the player's Cards in a function? like so:

```
///<summary>
/// Function to show current cards
/// </summary>
public static void ViewCards(object player)
{
    var cards = player.Cards  // This line doesn't work
    foreach (var card in cards)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{card.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Attack: {card.Attack}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Defense: {card.Defense}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Cost: ${card.Cost}");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change  the method signature Change the player parameter  , from `Object` to `Player`

```
public static void ViewCards(Player player)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain a more OO approach you could make it a method on the player.

```
class Player
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Balance {get;set;}
    public List<Card> Cards {get;set;}

    public void ViewCards()
    {
        foreach (var card in Cards)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{card.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Attack: {card.Attack}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Defense: {card.Defense}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Cost: ${card.Cost}");
        }    
    }
}
```

And then on some method

```
player.ViewCards();
```

Also you should not use public fields, instead use a Property. This promotes better encapsulation and class cohesiveness. I am referring here to `Name`, `Balance`, and `Cards`. The `get;` and `set;` will create a backing field during compile time.

Comment: I love your suggestion. Thanks I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AhmadAbdullahAwayhan - no problem. If you like it please remember to upvote (different from marking as answer as you can upvote multiple answers). You do that using the up arrow next to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the object to class Player

```
///<summary>
/// Function to show current cards
/// </summary>
public static void ViewCards(object player)
{
    var cards = (player as Player)?.Cards;  // cast object to Player, returs null if object is not of correct type

    if (cards != null)
    {
       foreach (var card in cards)
       { 
           Console.WriteLine($"{card.Name}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Attack: {card.Attack}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Defense: {card.Defense}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Cost: ${card.Cost}");
       }  
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify object type, you can use dynamic

```
public static void ViewCards(dynamic player)
{
    var cards = player.Cards  // This line doesn't work
    foreach (var card in cards)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{card.Name}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Attack: {card.Attack}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Defense: {card.Defense}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Cost: ${card.Cost}");
    }    
}
```

But you may have an exception on runtime if your object doesn't have a property Cards